# Will full size slideshow links separate from thumbnails preload?

Tags: fancybox, slideshow, preload

I am using Fancybox. In a slideshow where the thumbnails are not reduced from larger images, and are linked to separate full-size images (that will appear in the slideshow when thumbnails are clicked), will the full-size images also pre-load with the webpage? Or only load when the slideshow is activated? My slideshows have many images, and I don't want them to load until necessary. Thanks in advance for advice!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use developer tools to easily check network activity. 
The script fully loads current and previous/next slides after it is activated. Thumbnails are, hoverer, all loaded at once. This means, that if you have extremely large quantities of images, the script will load only max 3 of them and it would be better to disable thumbnails.